# Property declaration for to-many relationships in Core Data

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, core-data

I have an application written using Core Data.  I have 2 entities with a one-to-many relationship.  I have subclassed NSManagedObject for both of them.  The entity on the one-side is called Playlist and the other is called Song.

The interface for Playlist:

```
@interface VBPlaylist : NSManagedObject {
}

@property (readwrite, copy) NSString *name;

@end
```

The implementation for Playlist:

```
@implementation VBPlaylist

@dynamic name;

@end
```

I think that I should have another property to indicate the Songs under the Playlist class.  I cannot find any sample code that shows to-many relationships written as properties.  How do you do this?

Comment: Also, have a look at [this blog post](http://nvie.com/archives/263 "Automatically generate classes for your Core Data data model") for extremely easy **automatic** generation of the classes.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To-one relationships are modeled as object references by Core Data. So a to-one relationship from Entity `Bar` to entity `Baz` (assuming `Baz` is implemented by the class `Baz`) would be

```
@interface Bar : NSManagedObject {
}

@property (readwrite,nonatomic) Baz * toBaz;

@end
```

To-many relationships are modeled as a mutable set property (though *not* as an `NSMutableSet`). Assuming a to-many relationship from `Bar` to `Baz` called `manyBazz`:

```
@interface Bar : NSManagedObject {

}

@property (retain) NSSet* manyBazz;

@end

// coalesce these into one @interface AnalysisRecord (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors) section
@interface Bar (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)
- (void)addManyBazzObject:(Baz *)value;
- (void)removeManyBazzObject:(Baz *)value;
- (void)addManyBazz:(NSSet *)value;
- (void)removeManyBazz:(NSSet *)value;

@end
```

If you want to use the NSMutableSet interface to manipulate the `manyBazz` relationship, you should call `-mutableSetValueForKey:@"manyBazz"` to get a KVO-compliant proxy for the `manyBazz` relationship.

On Leopard (OS X 10.5) and later, all appropriate methods are automaticall generated at run-time by the Core Data framework, even if  you do not explicitly declare or implement them (you will, of course, get a compiler warning if you try to use them without declaring them in a header file). Thus you do not *need* to subclass

The easiest way to get the declaration and implementation right is to select the attributes in the data modeler and choose "Copy Objective-C 2.0 Method Declarations To Clipboard" from the "Design->Data Model" menu, the paste into your implementing classes .h file. Of course, you have to keep your .h and model in sync... hence a hearty recommendation for rentzsch's awesome [MO Generator](http://rentzsch.github.com/mogenerator/), a tool that will automatically generate (and re-generate) NSManagedObject subclasses from your data model.

Comment: So in this case if I want to add a Baz object to Bar I can do:
[barInstance addManyBazzObject:bazInstance] or bazInstance.bar=barInstance?

Comment: I think you forgot to finish that last sentence.

Comment: Thanks, Peter. Oops. Should be fixed now.

Comment: Sadly, it looks like the link for "MO Generator" is broken now.

Comment: @Chris, the link should be fixed. In the future, please feel free to fix errors like this in other's posts yourself; everyone benefits from some constant TLC to useful information. I'm not sure where the rep cutoff is for edits like this but I'm sure you'll soon be there.

Comment: @Barry I agree; I was actually going to edit your post myself, but [a quick search for MO Generator](http://www.google.com/search?q=mo+generator) didn't turn up any results and I was too lazy to dig much deeper.  :p

Answer (score 16):

The simplest way to create .h and .m files for your CoreData entities is this:

1. Select an entity in the data modeler.
2. Press Command-N or select File->New File…
3. Select 'Cocoa' from the source list.
4. In the template chooser, you should now see an item called 'Managed Object Class'. If this isn't there, click Cancel and repeat steps 1-2.
5. Press Next, choose the project/target, and press Next again.
6. Now you see something like the following window: [New Managed Object Class window http://blog.alanquatermain.net/images/ManagedObjectClass.png](http://blog.alanquatermain.net/images/ManagedObjectClass.png)
7. Select the options you need and click Finish.

This will generate the following header and source files:

Entity.h:

```
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>


@interface Entity :  NSManagedObject  
{
}

@property (retain) NSNumber * uniqueID;
@property (retain) NSString * name;
@property (retain) Entity * parent;
@property (retain) NSSet* children;

@end

@interface Entity (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)
- (void)addChildrenObject:(Entity *)value;
- (void)removeChildrenObject:(Entity *)value;
- (void)addChildren:(NSSet *)value;
- (void)removeChildren:(NSSet *)value;

@end
```

Entity.m:

```
#import "Entity.h"


@implementation Entity 

@dynamic uniqueID;
@dynamic name;
@dynamic parent;
@dynamic children;

@end
```

Note that the implementation doesn't contain anything except `@dynamic` markers to tell the compiler not to worry about missing methods/variables to match the properties.

Comment: Cool.  The generated code makes for good examples for how to set this up.  I have been using it a lot today.

Answer (score 2):

This has slightly changed.  As of 4.2.1 (March 2012), you go to New File; select Core Data (not Cocoa), and then select New NSObjectModel subclass.  From there it produces the subclass as described above.

Comment: Also, `CMD+N` instead of file->new