# Subclass UITextField with a core-data entity as a property

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uitextfield

I'd like to tie a core-data entity to a UITextField so that whenever the the textField finishes editing, it will automatically update the core-data object.

Here's how I'd like it work– not sure if it's possible.

- `user` is a core-data entity
- `user.gender` is a field of that entity
- `genderField` is a UITextField
- `genderField.coreDataObject` is a NSManagedObject property

  1. A user types content into a `genderField`
  2. On finish, the `genderField` fires `didEndEditing`
  3. In `didEndEditing`, the `genderField` sets the `user.gender` by saying `genderField.coreDataObject = genderField.text`

The problem is that the coreDataObject is the `user` and not `user.gender`. So, first of all, you can't set the `coreDataObject` equal to a string.

I need to store `coreDataObject` but then somehow set `coreDataObject.gender = genderField.text`

Thanks.

Comment: What's the error/is happening? Does it crash?

Comment: Just updated my question because I wasn't clear. The problem is that the coreDataObject is the user and not user.gender. So, you can't set the coreDataObject equal to a string. I need to set `coreDataObject.gender = genderField.text` but am not sure how to access that property

Comment: Have you generated classes for your `NSManagedObject` entity? If not try `[genderField.coreDataObject setValue:genderField.text forKey:@"gender"]`.

Comment: Whoa- Awesome! That works! Okay I didn't realize you could set it like that. If you want to put that as an answer below, I will mark it as the correct answer

Comment: As an addendum, have you considered generating NSManagedObject subclasses for your entities? It would make it possible to access their properties via standard getters/setters, and give you all those sweet, sweet, compile time checks.

Comment: @BrianW thanks, and glad it worked. I've referenced another answer in mine if you want to go down the custom `NSManagedObject` route :)

Comment: You are mixing model and view, don't you? You should set your view controller as delegate for the text field and receive a notice when ever the text changes and save its new value in CD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either generate custom subclass your `NSManagedObject` or use key-value coding.

```
[genderField.coreDataObject setValue:genderField.text forKey:@"gender"]
```

As echoed by AlexDG, you might be better off eventually going down the generating route. But for now the above works for your needs!

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2379396/849645) for more info on generating your own classes!