# Difficulty writing number value back to Core Data

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsnumber, nsinteger

I have a `Core Data` entity called **Status** with two attributes **savedMessageID** as Integer32 and **savedMessageText** as String.

I have a string stored in an SQL database which the app downloads on startup. The string from the database is broken down into two parts ID and text:

```
    NSInteger *newMessageID = [the_ID_as_a_string integerValue];
    NSString *newMessageText = the_message_as_a_string;
```

I then read the **Core Data** record and compare the IDs to see if there has been a change. If the downloaded ID is greater than the stored ID the new message is displayed. This is working fine so far.

I then try to write back to **Core Data** with the new downloaded ID. Here is the problem ... much talked about on here already I know:

```
NSEntityDescription *entitydesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Status" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSManagedObject *updatedStatus = [[NSManagedObject alloc]initWithEntity:entitydesc insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];
[updatedStatus setValue:newMessageID forKey:@"savedMessageID"]; //**error line**
[updatedStatus setValue:newMessageText forKey:@"savedMessageText"];
NSError *error;
[context save:&error];
```

It seems I can't write back an `NSInteger` back to the `Core Data` . I have tried writing NSNumber, int etc but all of these flag up issues. Any ideas how I should do this?

** The error I am getting is *implicit conversion of non-Objective-C pointer to NSInteger *' (aka 'int *') to 'id' is disallowed with ARC*

Comment: What's the actual error you are receiving?

Comment: NSInteger is just an int type (works out to be a long in LP64 arch's) so you if you passed that in how could Core Data interpret it to be anything other than an address of an NSNumber? that is how it works... what error are you getting, does save fail, or are you getting a value that you don't expect, when you read from another context?

Comment: The Error is - implicit conversion of non-Objective-C pointer to NSInteger *' (aka 'int *') to 'id' is disallowed with ARC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’ve made a mistake. Property `[the_ID_as_a_string integerValue]` returns integer value, not a pointer to it. Properly is:

```
NSInteger newMessageID = [the_ID_as_a_string integerValue];
```

and then setting value (expected is NSNumber):

```
[updatedStatus setValue:@(newMessageID) forKey:@"savedMessageID"];
```

or

```
[updatedStatus setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:newMessageID] forKey:@"savedMessageID"];
```

I suggest you to generate strict models to avoid type mismatch (see answers here [How to create classes after creating Core Data model in Xcode for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023769/how-to-create-classes-after-creating-core-data-model-in-xcode-for-iphone)).

Comment: I afraid I don't understand. I thought I would want the integer value rather than a pointer. Also numberFromInteger doesn't seem to exist for me. Are you suggesting that Core Data is expecting an NSNumber type to be written back?

Comment: It's `[NSNumber numberWithInteger:]` - my mistake. It looks like you don't read Apple documentation. NSNumber is well documented. Also if you type `[NSNumber number` - Xcode will suggest you proper methods - look at them. CoreData expects numeric values embedded in NSNumber, but if you create model classes you may have typed properties.

Comment: Got it now - thanks. Works a treat. I do read the Apple docs but this one has had me stumped. Cheers.

Comment: Regarding generating model classes - I suggest you to use mogenerator instead of Xcode. It works really great.